# How to use a mysql table of a particular django app in another django app if the is same?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying my hand at Python. I have a created a simple app with MySQL as a back end and I want to use the application's table in another app.

Both of the applications are for the same project. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your app in registered in settings.py.Then import the model to other by `appname.models.Modelname.`

Execute Query:

```
ModelName.objects.all()
```